# Empty function not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```php
if(!empty($this->input->post())){
   Var_dump($this->input-post());
}
```

this shows me Fatal Error

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in D:\install\wamp\www\CI\application\controllers\user\user.php on line 39

I don't understand why this is happening.
In the CodeIgniter in controller file I have written this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
if(!empty($this->input->post())){
   Var_dump($this->input-post());
}
```

to

```
if($this->input->post()){
   var_dump($this->input-post());
}
```